# Is it possible to join nested queries?

Tags: sql

I am trying two nested queries.

```
select * from 
   select a.*, b.* from( 
   (select AAA, BBB from Atable) a) as AA,
   select * from (
   (select QQQ, BBB from Btable)b) as BB
where AA.AAA = 'Y' and AA.BBB = BB.BBB
```

is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select * from 
   (select AAA, BBB from Atable) a
      inner join
   (select QQQ, BBB from Btable)b
      on
         a.BBB = b.BBB
where a.AAA = 'Y'
```

I'm not sure what the extra levels of nesting and aliasing in your question were trying to achieve.

Comment: @TejasVaishnav - if you're working with a database engine with a decent optimizer (the OP hasn't indicated what they're using) then the performance should be identical. I'd certainly refrain from statements that include the word "always" if I didn't know what database system was being used.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you going for instead query for this type of queries

```
select * 
from 
   select a.*, b.* 
   from
       ( 
           (select AAA, BBB from Atable) a) as AA,
           select * 
           from (
                  (select QQQ, BBB from Btable) b) as BB
where 
    AA.AAA = 'Y' and AA.BBB = BB.BBB
```

You can use any join like inner join, left outer join etc. like this

```
select 
    AA.AAA, AA.BBB, BB.QQQ 
from 
    Atable as AA
inner join
    Btable as BB ON BB.BBB = AA.BBB
where
    AA.AAA = 'Y'
```

Comment: Let me try both these options and will come back if needed